How to fix llvmlite and numba error for Python 3.11?
I'm creating a python project using whisper to convert mp3 to text.
When I try to run "poetry add whisper", I got the following message:
libc = ctypes.CDLL(libc_name)

After searching on the internet, I've found that this is not the correct whisper library and that I should use "poetry add openai-whisper". However, when trying to run this second installation, I got another error message, this time:
Note: This error originates from the build backend, and is 
likely not a problem with poetry but with llvmlite (0.34.0) 
not supporting PEP 517 builds. You can verify this by running 
'pip wheel --no-cache-dir --use-pep517 "llvmlite (==0.34.0)"'.

Then I've read many posts on the subject and most of them are inconclusive. Those that tried to provide an answer, usually indicates one of these answers:

llvmlite does not have support for python 3.9
pip install llvmlite==0.36.0
update your pip
Download llvmlite latest version

There were more answers, but I can't remember all of them, I've been stuck with this since the beginning of this week and couldn't find any solution that works well.
The first one would mean that I need to change to Python 3.9, but I was hoping there was another option. For the second answer, I didn't do pip install llvmlite==0.36.0, but poetry add llvmlite==0.36.0 and the error message I've received was:
The current project's supported Python range (>=3.11,<4.0) is not
compatible with some of the required packages Python requirement:
llvmlite requires Python >=3.6,<3.10, so it will not be satisfied 
for Python >=3.11,<4.0

For the third option, I updated pip, but it didn't change anything. For the last one, I'm not sure why would this work, since I've read some error messages indicating that numba depends on llvmlite 0.31. But I've tried anyway, this was the error message:
ERROR: llvmlite-0.43.0-cp312-cp312-win_amd64.whl is not a supported 
wheel on this platform.

So, I have no idea where is the problem and how to fix it, even after spending hours searching. Can anyone help me?

These are my sources:

Can't install numba on Python 3.10
llvmlite failed to install. Error building llvmlite
https://github.com/numba/llvmlite/issues/625
Installing numba and llvmlite Python on Windows 10 fail


Have you tried installing numba first? i.e. poetry add numba==0.60.0 openai-whisper
